# ¿como incorporar un editor de texto a mi formulario?

Tags: reactjs

Hola coders estoy creando un blog con React y al crear el formulario para realizar publicaciones o posteos para el blog, quisiera saber con incorporar un editor de texto en dicho formulario, el objetivo seria que al querer publicar pueda realizar acciones tales como, colocar negrita, hacer saltos de linea, poder adjuntar alguna que otra fotografía etc. Seria algo así como en esta pagina, en este momento estoy formulando mi pregunta y tengo un editor el cual me ayuda a realizar ciertas acciones a la hora de escribir texto. Desde ya Gracias.

```
 <div className='writeFormGroup'>
      <textarea
        className='descInput'
        placeholder='Escribe aquí...'
        type='text'
        autoFocus={true}
        name='desc'
        value={input.desc}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
    <button className='btnSubmit' type='submit'>
      PUBLICAR
    </button>
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y basada en opiniones, los cuales son motivos de [cierre](/help/closed-questions) de la misma. Procura que tu pregunta esté delineada a un problema en específico. Hay muchos editores de texto.

Answer (score 0):

[Trix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trix) te puede ayudar con lo que buscas. Puedes hasta adjuntar archivos

Answer (score 0):

este editor es muy bueno, yo lo utilizo, se llama **TinyMCE**.
Debes cargar un par de archivos js en la pagina donde tienes el formulario y luego al campo textarea que desees aplicarselo le colocas

```
class="tinymce-simple"
```

Sigue este link para que lo tengas más claro.

https://www.tiny.cloud/

Comment: Gracias lo voy a probar.

Comment: Funciono de 10, lo que no funciona es que me toma como parte del formulario para escribir las publicaciones.